# Ag-grid How can I have set-filter and text-filter on the same grid column

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In my application, I want to have a set-filter and text-filter on the same grid column. How can I achieve this? I have searched for so many places. Still, no luck.

Please help me. Thanks...

Comment: do you mean set-filter and text-filter ? Is it on same column or same grid? Need more details, code to answer

Comment: @PratikBhat, on the same column. I have updated the question.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a test filter

Comment: @PratikBhat, It is text-filter. We can search for a string value using that filter.

Comment: @Sai set filter do come with search area which allows you to enter text/string to narrow dropdown option so that you can select from filtered list. also you can have either set/text/number or date filter you can't have more than one filter on column. if you are an enterprise user you may ask support to provide you solution with your use case.